# Source for Flash based RSS1/RSS2/ATOM/RDF reader?

Tags: flash, actionscript, rss, rdf, atom-feed

Does anyone know where to find a good, opensource RSS reader in Flash? I see lots that implement RSS or ATOM or RSS2, but none that do all of the different RSS style formats out there. I'd prefer to keep this in Flash, as I'm trying to keep this so it'll run with minimal server requirements...

Requirements:
- Parses RSS1/RSS2/ATOM/RDF, and more if possible
- Works in ActionScript 2
- Is preferabbly opensource, though I will consider commercial if it comes with source code.

Thanks,

Brad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [as3syndicationlib](http://code.google.com/p/as3syndicationlib/)? It is written in ActionScript 3, but if you really need it in ActionScript 2, I think you could easily port it.

> Use the syndication library to parse
>   Atom and all versions of RSS easily.
>   This library hides the differences
>   between the formats so you can parse
>   any type of feed without having to
>   know what kind of feed it is.